# What are the default semantics for Spring transactions?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I'm looking at code that has annotation driven spring transactions declared, DAOs annotated with `@Repository` that use the `HibernateOperations` class - but the are no `@Transactional` annotations anywhere and no `tx:advice` in the xml files.

What is meant to happen if you don't actually annotate with `@Transactional`?

Comment: Strange... Maybe some AOP interceptor or servlet filter used?

Comment: Had a look for those too .. it's very strange - I have found one DAO with from an included module with @Transactional